# creating network using pybrain

Tags: python-3.5

I want to create a network using pybrain..I have installed anaconda on my windows(64bit)..so I have the dependencies installed...when I run the code

```
>>> from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
```

in Idle I face this error:

```
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
 from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
 File "C:\Users\ata\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pybrain\tools\shortcuts.py",     line 14
     except     ImportError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have shrtcuts code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2AB6.png)
I also have the buildNetwork function:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUuqW.png)

I ll be grateful if someone can tell me the reason...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that pybrain doesnt work for python 3,although in its website it is written that it works for python 2.5+.